# Why does Devise show these errors when saving user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

[image]

```
#view/devise/registrations/new.html.erb


    <div class="authform">
  <%= resource%>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <h3>Sign up</h3>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :avatar, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'  %>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
          </div>
      </div>

      <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Имя %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Фамилия %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Страна %>
      <%= collection_select(:city, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name) %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Город %>
     <%= collection_select(f, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Пароль %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
     <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

here I would like to make an input form `city_id` but somewhere in the older versions (you can see from the comment out the line) I introduced them as strings, and now I get the error..

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #force_ssl
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :avatar,:conversation_params,
             :city_id, :message_params, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || user_path(resource)
  end
end
```

and this migration file for cities and countries

```
# migration file 
class AddCounriesAndCitiesToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :city_id, :integer

    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string   :name
      t.integer  :country_id
    end
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string   :name
    end
  end
end
```

models/user.rb in brief

```
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :city
```

and city.rb

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :country
    has_many :users
end
```

I do not quite understand where the error can be ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. problem with devise validate

i just del this from models/user.rb

```
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :city
```

and add  it to controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, exception: [:show, :index]
  protect_from_forgery

  def index
    user_up
  end

  def show
    user_up
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_city = City.find_by id: @user.city_id
    @user_country = Country.find_by id: @user_city.country_id
  end

private  

  def user_up
    @users = User.all
    @city = City.all
    @country = Country.all
  end

end
```

and update select in view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :City %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

and in show method add this code

```
  <p>Country: <%= @user_country.name%></p>
  <p>City: <%= @user_city.name%></p>
```

i think it help you.

Answer (score 0):

i think in your permitted parameter your adding a column in two different table right? in one trigger?

try to convert your code like this

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up , keys: [:email, :password, :remember_me, :city, :country ])
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in , keys: [:email, :password, :remember_me])
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update , keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password ])
```

end

Comment: don't work.  i think 

code:## (def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :avatar,:conversation_params,
             :city_id, :message_params, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end)

same

Comment: i just want to clarify when you filling up the new.html.erb it will go to the model user and then? to the city model right?

Answer (score 0):

try to understand this code

or you can convert your code to this

i have user model and teacher model

i use devise for my authentication when user sign in

here's the code

```
    <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <% resource.build_teacher if resource.teacher.nil? %>
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= teacher_fields.text_field :firstname, placeholder: 'First Name' %>
      <%= teacher_fields.text_field :lastname, placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
</div>

 <div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %>
<% if @minimum_password_length %>
<em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
<% end %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%# raise params %>
<%= f.submit 'Sign up' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

in this form i filling up a email, password , firstname and lastname

email, password are for user model and firstname, lastname are for teacher model

this is my user model user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_one :teacher, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher
end
```

and this is my teacher.rb

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
validates :firstname, uniqueness: {scope: :lastname}, presence: true
validates :lastname, presence: true
end
```

my application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :authenticate_user!
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


def new
# Override Devise default behaviour and create a profile as well
build_resource({})
resource.build_teacher
respond_with self.resource
end

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up , keys: [:email, :password, :remember_me, :teacher_attributes => [:user_id, :firstname, :lastname]])
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in , keys: [:email, :password, :remember_me])
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update , keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password ])

end

end
```

i think we have similarity use that for a reference you can comment if i have mistake and i will accept it im also new in ruby on rails

Comment: Writing multiple answers by the same user is inappropriate. The only situation where posting multiple answers to the same question may be appropriate is when each of the answers, on its own, could be a valid and complete answer to the question. You should edit your answer to update it.